# Windows application data encryption that is only decryptable by same digitally signed app

Tags: windows, encryption, cryptography

Is there a Windows API (preferably with a managed .NET wrapper) that allows data to be encrypted and the same data to only be decrypted when called from the same digitally signed application?

For example, I have a cached security token for the desktop application that gets sent to the server.  This token is used on login when the user checks "Remember me".  I'd like to encrypt this token that the application stores in such a way that only my application that encrypted it can decrypt it.  I can't have the key/iv hard-coded in the application.  Somehow the OS (Windows) must support something like this where it uses a digital signature on the entry point's executable file to validate and allow the decryption.

I need to avoid having the user enter any credentials to encrypt/decrypt this token.  The whole point of auto-login is for the user to not have to enter credentials.

Yes, the cached login is a security risk, but restricting the token usage to the digitally signed application reduces the surface area exposed.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think desktop Windows apps can do that. Windows store apps probably can, I think they have some per-install security stuff.

The closest thing for desktops is probably [ProtectedData class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata?view=netframework-4.7.2) from .NET. Specify `DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser` to use some OS-provided crypto key specific to user account.

Don’t forget about `optionalEntropy` argument. I usually use a buffer from random.org I hardcode in the source.

Comment: That’s currently what we are doing. Trying to eliminate anything hard-coded in the app.

Comment: @MikeJansen Are you trying to protect from malware running in the same user session? I don’t think you really can. The reason why it more or less works for UWP is because UWP apps run in well-isolated containers.